# How do I parse the HTML on a page to find the largest gif and videos thumbnail?

Tags: python, video, web-scraping, gif, urllib3

Using python. I'd like to pass in a url and then get the HTML from the URL. I figure I can use the urllib to do this.

The next part is slightly more complicated. I would like to parse the HTML to find the main (defined to be biggest in size) gif and video in the HTML, if it exists. I would then like to take a screenshot, or get a thumbnail of the gif or video should it exist.

This seems like quite an interesting problem, and I think it can definetly be solved. I'm still thinking about the problem but would like to hear anyone else's thoughts?

Comment: First question is, why? But I reckon you have your reasons. Second question, what do you mean "biggest in size" ? As in bytes, rendered pixels, actual pixels?

Comment: 1. Just trying to get more experience in web scraping and this seems like a cool tools. 2. Well, let's just say actual pixels, but if another measurement would be more suited/easier to find they are good to.

Comment: If you need actual pixels, it can be as simple as getting all the GIF/Videos from that page, run them through (e.g.) ImageMagick/mplayer and get the values out. Rendered pixels can be a *lot* trickier, as you need a HTML/CSS rendering engine to do it correctly. That, plus there might even be differences between the engines.

Comment: The Python Imaging Library (PIL) adds image processing capabilities to your Python interpreter. This library supports many file formats, and provides powerful image processing and graphics capabilities.

http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/index.htm

Comment: @BartFriederichs thanks for that insight. so I could use ImageMagick to get the thumbnails from the html gif/videos - is that correct? Or would ImageMagick just get their sizes?

Comment: ImageMagick was just an example. The PIL could also be used. You have to use a HTML parser to get the <img> tags, then load whatever is in the src, and run that through PIL or ImageMagick, or whatever you choose.

Comment: I'm a little confused- they wouldn't be img tags if I'm looking at videos/gifs would they? Or do you mean each gif and video element has an img tag within it specifying its thumbnail? Thanks again